# Authentication state in ASP.NET MVC ActionFilters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, httpcontext, action-filter

I have an ActionFilter name of `Log` that it log user ip and other details when user login to the website so for do this work I write following code:

```
public class Log : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public IAppUserManager UserManager { get; set; }
    
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var status = filterContext.Controller.TempData.Any(pair => pair.Key == "status" && (int)pair.Value == 200);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User != null && filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && status)
        {
            var logIp = new AddIpAddressDto()
            {
                Browser = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetBrowser(),
                Ip = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetIp(),
                Os = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent.GetOs(),
                UrlReferrer = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer?.ToString(),
                UserId = Guid.Parse(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId()),
                UserName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserName(),
            };
            UserManager.Log(logIp);
        }
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

this code work when that `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is **ture**.

The `Log` Filter declare on Login Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("sign-in", Name = "signInRoute")]
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Log]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginDto login, string returnTo)
{
     var signInStatus = await _signInManager
         .PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, login.Password, login.RememberMe, true)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

     switch (signInStatus) // is Success
     {
         case SignInStatus.Success:
              TempData["status"] = 200;
              return RedirectToLocal(returnTo);
         case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                // todo return time of louckout
              break;
         case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
              return RedirectToAction("ConfirmEmail");
         case SignInStatus.Failure:
              return View(CleanPassWordInLogin(login));
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
     }
}
```

Login Action Works fine and `signInStatus` is **Success** but after excuted Action `IsAuthenticated` is **false**.

To solve this issue I've tried the following items:

- Used `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();`
- Defined following code in IoC (**StructureMap 4.5.2**)

  `config.For<HttpContextBase>().Use(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));`
- Tried `OnActionExecuted`,`OnActionExecuting`,`OnResultExecuting`
- Used `IAuthenticationManager` in Identity 2.0

How Can I Solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the execution of `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`, the authentication cookie will be created which includes the user info. So `User.Identity` info will be filled by the claims from the authentication cookie, which are not parsed yet (this cookie will be parsed in the second request to the server, not in the same login request). That's why you can't use `User.Identity` just after `PasswordSignInAsync`. At this specific point, you have only one option to find the userId:

```
 string userId = UserManager.FindByName(model.Email)?.Id;
```